# How to use a class name as a variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three classes `class_a.dart`, `class_b.dart`, and `class_c.dart`.

Each one contains a static method by the same name `myMethod():String` which returns a slightly different string based on which class it belongs to. (there is just one shared method for this example, but each class contains hundreds of methods all sharing names with methods in the other two classes)

Within an unrelated class `class_z.dart`, I can call `ClassA.myMethod()`, `ClassB.myMethod()`, and `ClassC.myMethod()`. These calls work as expected. Each time I need to make one of these calls, I can can use this structure to make sure I call the right one:

```dart
switch (usersChoice) {
     case "A":
          return ClassA.myMethod();

     case "B":
          return ClassB.myMethod();

     case "C":
          return ClassC.myMethod();

     default:
          handleError();
}
```

This switch statement works as expected; however, due to the nature of `class_z.dart`, it isn't ideal because it is repeated throughout the code several hundred times using other methods in addition to `myMethod():String`.

I know you can use `Type desiredClass = ClassA` to get a class type as a variable. My goal was to set the `desiredClass` variable at the beginning of the program and call each method like this:

```dart
/// The class the user wants to use.
Type desiredClass;

// Set [desiredClass] at the beginning.
void setDesiredClass(String usersChoice) {
     switch (usersChoice) {
          case "A":
               desiredClass = ClassA;
               break;

          case "B":
               desiredClass = ClassB;
               break;

          case "C":
               desiredClass = ClassC;
               break;

          default:
               handleError();
     }
}

/// Returns a string from the user-selected class.
///
/// There are hundreds of methods like this one all calling
/// to hundreds of methods in the A, B, and C classes.
String method_1() {
     return desiredClass.myMethod();
}
```

By using the `setDesiredClass(String):void` method, I was hoping that all of the methods like `method_1():String` would be able to be one liners instead of having to use hundreds of switch trees in the code. Unfortunately, this did not work. The only way I can see to do this is by using hundreds of switch trees.

Comment: How much do you know about OOP or interfaces?

Comment: @nvoigt I have a decent handle on OOP but interfaces could use some work, but I understand it well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with `static` methods. You can create a class or an interface and either derive from that class or implement that interface (now you see why it doesn't work with static methods, they cannot be overriden or be part of an interface).

Then your example becomes this:

```
YourBaseClassOrInterface? desiredClass;

// Set [desiredClass] at the beginning.
void setDesiredClass(String usersChoice) {
     switch (usersChoice) {
          case "A":
               desiredClass = ClassA();
               break;

          case "B":
               desiredClass = ClassB();
               break;

          case "C":
               desiredClass = ClassC();
               break;

          default:
               handleError();
     }
}
```

Note that you now have assigned an *instance* of your respective class, not a type.